# how to check for '\t'?

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream, character-arrays

I have a code that reads in a text file, and turns each word from the file into a character array (needs to be a character array, no strings allowed) that's a data member of a Word class. When a punctuation is encountered, all the Word objects get stored into a Sentence class as a linked list. When a tab is encountered, all the Sentences before are stored in a Paragraph class as a linked list. What I need help with is a way to check for '\t' in the text file. I'm reading in using

```
while(myFile >> charArray){
//stuff
}
```

As this reads in a full word and stores it in `charArray`. If it is the end of a sentence, `charArray[size]` (size being the last element) will `== '.' || == "!" || == "?"` so I can handle making a new Sentence every time (I can assume the text file will be properly formatted every time). What I don't know how to do is how to check for the '\t' character to make a new paragraph. Will '\t' get picked up by `myFile >> charArray`? I tried messing around with various `if` statements to see if I could pick up a '\t' character but I haven't been able to. So how can I check for a tab while reading in from a text file into a character array?

Comment: Personally, I'd do it the good old fashioned K&R way: [fgetc()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc).

Comment: I suggest: 1. Read the file line by line.  2. Search for `'\t'` in the line and divide the line at the tabs. 3. Process each section of the divided line using `istrstream`.

Comment: This is C code unless you're using `std::string` which you should be because the alternative is terrifying.

Comment: Google "C++ read line into string" and "C++ split string at character". The "no strings allowed" part in non-nonsensical even if this is a homework question.

Comment: [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi) please, for some more sophisticated parsing concepts.

Comment: This is wrong: `== '.' || == "!" || == "?"`. You should only be looking at `chars` like this: `== '.' || == '!' || == '?'`. And to check for `\t` you need: `== '\t'`.

Comment: @Galik the "" was a typo, I didn't copy paste straight from the code

Answer (score 1):

iostreams `operator>>` will, by default, read and discard leading whitespace.  Including your tab character that begins a new paragraph.  I suggest that a blank line should also be considered a paragraph separator.  And many people use a run of normal space characters at the beginning of a line to produce indentation, instead of a tab, so you should check for that too.

My preferred approach would be to use `getline` to read an entire line of text, whitespace and all.  Test the first character and decide whether to start a new paragraph.  Then load that line into a stringstream and use `operator>>` to pull out individual words.  This is pretty similar to R Sahu's comment... but I would not split the line on tab characters.  Rather, you're concerned with tabs/spaces at the beginning of a line only.

You can also experiment with `noskipws` and [reading individual whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10946935/103167)

Comment: How would I read in using getline? I look around and I'm not sure I get it. I declared a `char line[256];` and then tried using `getline(myFile, line);` but I get an error saying no matching function call. I included <iostream>. So what would I need to do to get the read-in line into a buffer character array?

Comment: @TommyK: That's the syntax for reading into a `std::string`, which your question says you aren't allowed to use.  [The char-array version](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) is a member function, so you'd say `myFile.getline(line, 256);`

Answer (score 0):

This may help you/be what your looking for:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/

your interested in the overload provided by C++:

char * strchr (       char * str, int character );

this will return a pointer to the first occurance of the character, or, a null pointer if not found.

An example of usage (provided by Cplusplus.com as well) can be found here:

```
/* strchr example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "This is a sample string";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Looking for the 's' character in \"%s\"...\n",str);
  pch=strchr(str,'s');
  while (pch!=NULL)
  {
    printf ("found at %d\n",pch-str+1);
    pch=strchr(pch+1,'s');
  }
  return 0;
}
```